# Get typeof element inside of JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I have a JSON file and with the help of @Supercool was able to get key names for each. I wanted to be able to get the type of values.

JSON Structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1536700,
        "title": "final_output",
        "error": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "metric": 4940616.0,
                "title": "d_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 5132162.0,
                "title": "p_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4954576.0,
                "title": "s_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4882217.0,
                "title": "u_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4869609.0,
                "title": "t_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 5075422.0,
                "title": "w_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4461996.0,
                "title": "v_revenue"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Next Structure:

```
[
    {
        "run_id": 1536700,
        "code_title": "select_data",
        "error": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "user_name": "C_51",
                "num1": 51,
                "num2": 101,
                "num3": 151
            },
            {
                "user_name": "H_51",
                "num1": 51,
                "num2": 101,
                "num3": 151
            },
            {
                "user_name": "C_52",
                "num1": 52,
                "num2": 102,
                "num3": 152
            },
            {
                "user_name": "H_52",
                "num1": 52,
                "num2": 102,
                "num3": 152
            },
            {
                "user_name": "C_53",
                "num1": 53,
                "num2": 103,
                "num3": 153
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Use Object.keys(yourObject) to get the keys

```
 $.getJSON(api, function(elem) {
      let keys=elem.map( structure =>  Object.keys(structure.data[0]))         
   });
```

Run the following snippet to check if it works

```js
 let ele= [{"id": 1536700,"title": "final_output","error": "",
"data": [{"metric": 4940616.0,"title": "d_revenue"},{"metric": 5132162.0,"title": "p_revenue"},{"metric":4954576.0,"title": "s_revenue"},{"metric": 4882217.0,"title":"u_revenue"},{"metric": 4869609.0,"title":"t_revenue"},{"metric": 5075422.0,"title": "w_revenue"},{"metric": 4461996.0,"title": "v_revenue"}
]
},
{"run_id": 1536700,"code_title": "select_data","error": "",
  "data": [{"user_name": "C_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101,"num3": 151},{"user_name": "H_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101, "num3": 151},{"user_name": "C_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3": 152},{"user_name": "H_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3":152},{"user_name": "C_53","num1": 53,"num2": 103,"num3": 153}
]}]
 console.log(ele.map( structure =>  Object.keys(structure.data[0])))
 console.log(ele.map( structure =>  Object.values(structure.data[0])))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I want to be able to get the type of each of the values. Is it possible for me to get this for the values listed above?

```
[
  [
    number,
    string
  ],
  [
    string,
    number,
    number,
    number
  ]
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to preserve the keys?

Comment: @RoboRobok, what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of keeping that in an array, you could convert it to an object with values replaced to types. Not sure what you need it for though, but I'm almost 100% positive you do something funny.

Comment: @Supercool. for each of the values

Comment: @Supercool object keys are always strings in JavaScript.

Comment: `ele.map(structure => Object.values(structure.data[0]).map(v => typeof v))`

Comment: @RoboRobok just confirming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let ele = [{"id": 1536700,"title": "final_output","error": "", "data": [{"metric": 4940616.0,"title": "d_revenue"},{"metric": 5132162.0,"title": "p_revenue"},{"metric":4954576.0,"title": "s_revenue"},{"metric": 4882217.0,"title":"u_revenue"},{"metric": 4869609.0,"title":"t_revenue"},{"metric": 5075422.0,"title": "w_revenue"},{"metric": 4461996.0,"title": "v_revenue"}]}, {"run_id": 1536700,"code_title": "select_data","error": "", "data": [{"user_name": "C_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101,"num3": 151},{"user_name": "H_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101, "num3": 151},{"user_name": "C_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3": 152},{"user_name": "H_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3":152},{"user_name": "C_53","num1": 53,"num2": 103,"num3": 153}]}];

console.log(ele.map(structure => Object.values(structure.data[0]).map(v => typeof v)));
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that JavaScript does not guarantee object property order in every case.

Comment: using map will guarentee it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @Supercool. `map` doesn't guarantee property order, its the call to `Object.values()` which does.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `map()` through Object.values(obj) and use `typeof` value to return the type

```js
let ele= [{"id": 1536700,"title": "final_output","error": "",
"data": [{"metric": 4940616.0,"title": "d_revenue"},{"metric": 5132162.0,"title": "p_revenue"},{"metric":4954576.0,"title": "s_revenue"},{"metric": 4882217.0,"title":"u_revenue"},{"metric": 4869609.0,"title":"t_revenue"},{"metric": 5075422.0,"title": "w_revenue"},{"metric": 4461996.0,"title": "v_revenue"}
]
},
{"run_id": 1536700,"code_title": "select_data","error": "",
  "data": [{"user_name": "C_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101,"num3": 151},{"user_name": "H_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101, "num3": 151},{"user_name": "C_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3": 152},{"user_name": "H_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3":152},{"user_name": "C_53","num1": 53,"num2": 103,"num3": 153}
]}]
console.log("Keys are ..");
 console.log(ele.map( structure =>  Object.keys(structure.data[0])))
console.log("and their correspondent value types are ..."); 
 console.log(ele.map( structure =>  Object.values(structure.data[0]).map(value => typeof value)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a prototype language, so you can use the `constructor.name` property on any structure in js to see what type it is.

simple example:

```js
const a = { t: 5, s: '', d: false, e:[], f:{}, d:5.53 };
for (let k in a) {
  console.log(k,a[k].constructor.name);
}
```

Comment: Made a snippet and added the key since it does not log in order

Comment: map will guarantee it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order